# How do i make this slideshow?

Tags: jquery, css, slideshow

Im trying to replicate this code: https://codepen.io/jcoulterdesign/embed/arQoER?default-tab=result&editable=true&theme-id=dark
Its far too advanced for me so i want that when i click on each image there is a animation and fade with content.
The code is not reponsive and it is not dynamic if i add more content it stops working because its based on indexes
My source https://codepen.io/m-rio-renato/pen/dyVOyKq

```js
    $(document).ready(function (){
    
    //Quando se carrega no Botão animação acontece
    $('button').click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('btn-anim');
    });

    $('.slide_horizontal__slider').click(function(){
        var slide_contagem = 700;
        var slide_time = 500;
        var slide_index = $(this).index();

        if(slide_index <= 1){
            if(slide_index === 0){
                $('.slide_horizontal__slider__image__content').stop().fadeOut();
                $('.slide_horizontal__slider').stop().animate({'left': slide_contagem }, slide_time, function(){
                    $('.slide_horizontal__slider__image__content').eq(slide_index).fadeIn(slide_time);
                });
            }
            if(slide_index === 1){
                $('.slide_horizontal__slider__image__content').stop().fadeOut();
                $('.slide_horizontal__slider').stop().animate({'left': 0 }, slide_time, function(){
                    $('.slide_horizontal__slider__image__content').eq(slide_index).fadeIn(slide_time);
                });
            }
        }else{
            if(slide_index === 2){
                $('.slide_horizontal__slider__image__content').stop().fadeOut();
                $('.slide_horizontal__slider').stop().animate({'left': -slide_contagem }, slide_time, function(){
                    $('.slide_horizontal__slider__image__content').eq(slide_index).fadeIn(slide_time);
                });
            }
            if(slide_index === 3){
                $('.slide_horizontal__slider__image__content').stop().fadeOut();
                $('.slide_horizontal__slider').stop().animate({'left': -slide_contagem*2 }, slide_time, function(){
                    $('.slide_horizontal__slider__image__content').eq(slide_index).fadeIn(slide_time);
                });
            }
            if(slide_index === 4){
                $('.slide_horizontal__slider__image__content').stop().fadeOut();
                $('.slide_horizontal__slider').stop().animate({'left': -slide_contagem*3 }, slide_time, function(){
                    $('.slide_horizontal__slider__image__content').eq(slide_index).fadeIn(slide_time);
                });
            }
        }
    });
    
    
});
```

```css
/*
TODOS OS DIREITOS RESERVADOS 2021
Mário Renato Teixeira aka FuZz3
*/

/*==================        RESET DE MARGENS        ==================*/

*, html, body, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, figure, img, video, svg, article, main, section, aside, div, ol, ul, il, table, input, nav, footer, header
{box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0;text-decoration: none;}

/*
==============================
            FONTES
==============================
*/

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Work+Sans:wght@100;200;300;400;500;600;700;800&display=swap');

/*
==============================
            CORES
==============================
*/

:root{
    --branco: #FBFBFB;
    --preto: #30323D;
    --vermelho-claro: #FF8170;
    --vermelho: #EE6352;
    --vermelho-escuro: #A13527;
    --fonte-principal: 'Work Sans';
}

/*
==============================
        ELEMENTOS GERAIS
==============================
*/
body{font-family: var(--fonte-principal);font-size: 16px;width: 100%;
    background-color: var(--vermelho);color: var(--branco);overflow-x: hidden;
}
h1{font-family: var(--fonte-principal);font-weight: 600;
}
h2{font-family: var(--fonte-principal);font-weight: 500;
}
h3{font-family: var(--fonte-principal);font-weight: 400;
}
h4{font-family: var(--fonte-principal);font-weight: 400;
}
h5{font-family: var(--fonte-principal);font-weight: 400;
}
h6{font-family: var(--fonte-principal);font-weight: 400;
}
p{
    
}
a{cursor: pointer;
    
}
a:hover{
    
}
header{
    
}
footer{
    
}
button{background-color: var(--vermelho);border: none;color: var(--branco);
    font-size: 1.005em;padding: 10px 20px;margin: 20px 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
button:hover{outline: 2px solid var(--preto);}
.btn-anim{animation-name: btn; animation-iteration-count: 1;animation-duration: 0.3s;}
@keyframes btn{
    0%{transform: scale(0.9);}
    100%{transform: scale(1);}
}
img{width: 100%;display: block;}

.flex{display: flex;flex-direction: row;}

.container{position: relative;width: 100%;}
/*
==============================
            SLIDER
==============================
*/
.slide_horizontal{width: 100%;margin: 30px 0px;
    position: absolute;top: 0;left: 0px;font-size: 1.2em;
}
.slide_horizontal h4{font-size: 1.5em;padding-bottom: 10px}
.slide_horizontal p{font-size: 1.2em;padding-bottom: 10px}
.slide_horizontal__slider{margin: 0 50px;position: relative; left: 0px;}
.slide_horizontal__slider__image{position: relative;width: 600px;height: 400px; background-color: var(--branco);}
.slide_horizontal__slider__image__content{position: absolute;top: 0;left: 0;
    background-color: rgba(48,50,61,0.60);width: 100%;height: 100%;
    display: none;
}
.slide_horizontal__slider__image__content span{position: absolute; top: 40%;left: 10%;}
.slide_ativo{display: block;}
.slide_frente, .slide_tras{cursor: pointer;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <section class="slide_horizontal flex">

    <article class="slide_horizontal__slider">
      <h3>2016</h3>
      <figure class="slide_horizontal__slider__image">
        <!--<img src="media/img/slider_1.jpg" alt="Design multimedia for Slotfortes in 2016">-->

        <div class="slide_horizontal__slider__image__content">
          <span>
            <h4>Design Multimedia</h4>
            <p>Developed for Slotfortes</p>
            <a><button>Tell me more</button></a>
          </span>
        </div>
      </figure>
    </article>

    <article class="slide_horizontal__slider">
      <h3>2016</h3>
      <figure class="slide_horizontal__slider__image">
        <!--<img src="media/img/slider_1.jpg" alt="Design multimedia for Slotfortes in 2016">-->

        <div class="slide_horizontal__slider__image__content slide_ativo">
          <span>
            <h4>Design Multimedia</h4>
            <p>Developed for Slotfortes</p>
            <a><button>Tell me more</button></a>
          </span>
        </div>
      </figure>
    </article>

    <article class="slide_horizontal__slider">
      <h3>2016</h3>
      <figure class="slide_horizontal__slider__image">
        <!--<img src="media/img/slider_1.jpg" alt="Design multimedia for Slotfortes in 2016">-->

        <div class="slide_horizontal__slider__image__content">
          <span>
            <h4>Design Multimedia</h4>
            <p>Developed for Slotfortes</p>
            <a><button>Tell me more</button></a>
          </span>
        </div>
      </figure>
    </article>

    <article class="slide_horizontal__slider">
      <h3>2016</h3>
      <figure class="slide_horizontal__slider__image">
        <!--<img src="media/img/slider_1.jpg" alt="Design multimedia for Slotfortes in 2016">-->

        <div class="slide_horizontal__slider__image__content">
          <span>
            <h4>Design Multimedia</h4>
            <p>Developed for Slotfortes</p>
            <a><button>Tell me more</button></a>
          </span>
        </div>
      </figure>
    </article>

    <article class="slide_horizontal__slider">
      <h3>2016</h3>
      <figure class="slide_horizontal__slider__image">
        <!--<img src="media/img/slider_1.jpg" alt="Design multimedia for Slotfortes in 2016">-->

        <div class="slide_horizontal__slider__image__content">
          <span>
            <h4>Design Multimedia</h4>
            <p>Developed for Slotfortes</p>
            <a><button>Tell me more</button></a>
          </span>
        </div>
      </figure>
    </article>

  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Check the browser's console for any potential javascript error(s).

Comment: Did u saw my answer below ?

Answer (score 0):

For higher index > 2, you can just change by ***(slide_index-1)**.

Like this, you can add more content and it wont stop working.

```js
$(document).ready(function (){
    
    //Quando se carrega no Botão animação acontece
    $('button').click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('btn-anim');
    });

    $('.slide_horizontal__slider').click(function(){
        var slide_contagem = 700;
        var slide_time = 500;
        var slide_index = $(this).index();

        if(slide_index <= 1){
            if(slide_index === 0){
                $('.slide_horizontal__slider__image__content').stop().fadeOut();
                $('.slide_horizontal__slider').stop().animate({'left': slide_contagem }, slide_time, function(){
                    $('.slide_horizontal__slider__image__content').eq(slide_index).fadeIn(slide_time);
                });
            } else {
                $('.slide_horizontal__slider__image__content').stop().fadeOut();
                $('.slide_horizontal__slider').stop().animate({'left': 0 }, slide_time, function(){
                    $('.slide_horizontal__slider__image__content').eq(slide_index).fadeIn(slide_time);
                });
            }
        }else{
          if(slide_index === 2){
            $('.slide_horizontal__slider__image__content').stop().fadeOut();
            $('.slide_horizontal__slider').stop().animate({'left': -slide_contagem }, slide_time, function(){
              $('.slide_horizontal__slider__image__content').eq(slide_index).fadeIn(slide_time);
            });
          } else {
            $('.slide_horizontal__slider__image__content').stop().fadeOut();
            $('.slide_horizontal__slider').stop().animate({'left': -slide_contagem*(slide_index-1) }, slide_time, function(){
              $('.slide_horizontal__slider__image__content').eq(slide_index).fadeIn(slide_time);
            });     
          }
        }
    });
    
    
});
```

```css
/*
TODOS OS DIREITOS RESERVADOS 2021
Mário Renato Teixeira aka FuZz3
*/

/*==================        RESET DE MARGENS        ==================*/

*, html, body, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, figure, img, video, svg, article, main, section, aside, div, ol, ul, il, table, input, nav, footer, header
{box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0;text-decoration: none;}

/*
==============================
            FONTES
==============================
*/

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Work+Sans:wght@100;200;300;400;500;600;700;800&display=swap');

/*
==============================
            CORES
==============================
*/

:root{
    --branco: #FBFBFB;
    --preto: #30323D;
    --vermelho-claro: #FF8170;
    --vermelho: #EE6352;
    --vermelho-escuro: #A13527;
    --fonte-principal: 'Work Sans';
}

/*
==============================
        ELEMENTOS GERAIS
==============================
*/
body{font-family: var(--fonte-principal);font-size: 16px;width: 100%;
    background-color: var(--vermelho);color: var(--branco);overflow-x: hidden;
}
h1{font-family: var(--fonte-principal);font-weight: 600;
}
h2{font-family: var(--fonte-principal);font-weight: 500;
}
h3{font-family: var(--fonte-principal);font-weight: 400;
}
h4{font-family: var(--fonte-principal);font-weight: 400;
}
h5{font-family: var(--fonte-principal);font-weight: 400;
}
h6{font-family: var(--fonte-principal);font-weight: 400;
}
p{
    
}
a{cursor: pointer;
    
}
a:hover{
    
}
header{
    
}
footer{
    
}
button{background-color: var(--vermelho);border: none;color: var(--branco);
    font-size: 1.005em;padding: 10px 20px;margin: 20px 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
button:hover{outline: 2px solid var(--preto);}
.btn-anim{animation-name: btn; animation-iteration-count: 1;animation-duration: 0.3s;}
@keyframes btn{
    0%{transform: scale(0.9);}
    100%{transform: scale(1);}
}
img{width: 100%;display: block;}

.flex{display: flex;flex-direction: row;}

.container{position: relative;width: 100%;}
/*
==============================
            SLIDER
==============================
*/
.slide_horizontal{width: 100%;margin: 30px 0px;
    position: absolute;top: 0;left: 0px;font-size: 1.2em;
}
.slide_horizontal h4{font-size: 1.5em;padding-bottom: 10px}
.slide_horizontal p{font-size: 1.2em;padding-bottom: 10px}
.slide_horizontal__slider{margin: 0 50px;position: relative; left: 0px;}
.slide_horizontal__slider__image{position: relative;width: 600px;height: 400px; background-color: var(--branco);}
.slide_horizontal__slider__image__content{position: absolute;top: 0;left: 0;
    background-color: rgba(48,50,61,0.60);width: 100%;height: 100%;
    display: none;
}
.slide_horizontal__slider__image__content span{position: absolute; top: 40%;left: 10%;}
.slide_ativo{display: block;}
.slide_frente, .slide_tras{cursor: pointer;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <section class="slide_horizontal flex">

    <article class="slide_horizontal__slider">
      <h3>2016</h3>
      <figure class="slide_horizontal__slider__image">
        <!--<img src="media/img/slider_1.jpg" alt="Design multimedia for Slotfortes in 2016">-->

        <div class="slide_horizontal__slider__image__content">
          <span>
            <h4>Design Multimedia</h4>
            <p>Developed for Slotfortes</p>
            <a><button>Tell me more</button></a>
          </span>
        </div>
      </figure>
    </article>

    <article class="slide_horizontal__slider">
      <h3>2016</h3>
      <figure class="slide_horizontal__slider__image">
        <!--<img src="media/img/slider_1.jpg" alt="Design multimedia for Slotfortes in 2016">-->

        <div class="slide_horizontal__slider__image__content slide_ativo">
          <span>
            <h4>Design Multimedia</h4>
            <p>Developed for Slotfortes</p>
            <a><button>Tell me more</button></a>
          </span>
        </div>
      </figure>
    </article>

    <article class="slide_horizontal__slider">
      <h3>2016</h3>
      <figure class="slide_horizontal__slider__image">
        <!--<img src="media/img/slider_1.jpg" alt="Design multimedia for Slotfortes in 2016">-->

        <div class="slide_horizontal__slider__image__content">
          <span>
            <h4>Design Multimedia</h4>
            <p>Developed for Slotfortes</p>
            <a><button>Tell me more</button></a>
          </span>
        </div>
      </figure>
    </article>

    <article class="slide_horizontal__slider">
      <h3>2016</h3>
      <figure class="slide_horizontal__slider__image">
        <!--<img src="media/img/slider_1.jpg" alt="Design multimedia for Slotfortes in 2016">-->

        <div class="slide_horizontal__slider__image__content">
          <span>
            <h4>Design Multimedia</h4>
            <p>Developed for Slotfortes</p>
            <a><button>Tell me more</button></a>
          </span>
        </div>
      </figure>
    </article>

    <article class="slide_horizontal__slider">
      <h3>2016</h3>
      <figure class="slide_horizontal__slider__image">
        <!--<img src="media/img/slider_1.jpg" alt="Design multimedia for Slotfortes in 2016">-->

        <div class="slide_horizontal__slider__image__content">
          <span>
            <h4>Design Multimedia</h4>
            <p>Developed for Slotfortes</p>
            <a><button>Tell me more</button></a>
          </span>
        </div>
      </figure>
    </article>
    
    <article class="slide_horizontal__slider">
      <h3>XXXX</h3>
      <figure class="slide_horizontal__slider__image">
        <!--<img src="media/img/slider_1.jpg" alt="Design multimedia for Slotfortes in 2016">-->

        <div class="slide_horizontal__slider__image__content">
          <span>
            <h4>Design Multimedia</h4>
            <p>Developed for Slotfortes</p>
            <a><button>Tell me more</button></a>
          </span>
        </div>
      </figure>
    </article>
    
    <article class="slide_horizontal__slider">
      <h3>XXXX</h3>
      <figure class="slide_horizontal__slider__image">
        <!--<img src="media/img/slider_1.jpg" alt="Design multimedia for Slotfortes in 2016">-->

        <div class="slide_horizontal__slider__image__content">
          <span>
            <h4>Design Multimedia</h4>
            <p>Developed for Slotfortes</p>
            <a><button>Tell me more</button></a>
          </span>
        </div>
      </figure>
    </article>
    
    <article class="slide_horizontal__slider">
      <h3>XXXX</h3>
      <figure class="slide_horizontal__slider__image">
        <!--<img src="media/img/slider_1.jpg" alt="Design multimedia for Slotfortes in 2016">-->

        <div class="slide_horizontal__slider__image__content">
          <span>
            <h4>Design Multimedia</h4>
            <p>Developed for Slotfortes</p>
            <a><button>Tell me more</button></a>
          </span>
        </div>
      </figure>
    </article>

  </section>
</div>
```